# When a superclass extends JFrame

Tags: java, swing, jframe, extends

I am trying to use a class which extends JFrame to build a GUI.

ex : class Deck extends JFrame

The GUI is built in its constructor.

Now when I extend Deck from another class,

ex : class Pile extends Deck

New windows are being created whenever an instance of the subclass (Pile) is started.

Is this happening because the subclass is inheriting the superclass constructor and therefore creating another window?

Can this be avoided without modifying the Deck superclass?

Thanks.

Comment: Subclassing unnecessarily (almost always the case with `JFrame` and `JPanel`) is usually a bad idea.

Comment: If it is causing problems you need to rethink if Deck really needs to extend JFrame and the answer will probably be that it wont

Answer (score 2):

> Is this happening because the subclass
>   is inheriting the superclass
>   constructor and therefore creating
>   another window?

Yes. You extend a `JFrame`, so you get a `JFrame`.

`super()` is always called implicitely before your own constructor, unless you call `super(...)` or `this(...)` yourself. This needs to be the first call in your own constructor.

If you really want that behavior, you could write another constructor in your base class (`Deck`) like that:

```
public class Deck extends JFrame {
    public Deck(boolean createContent) {
        if( createContent ) {
            getContentPane().add(...);
            // ...
        }
    }

    public Deck() {
        this(true);
    }
}


public class Pile extends Deck {
    public Deck() {
        super(false);
        // ...
    }
}
```

You will still end up with a `JFrame` since you extend it, but the child components of your `Deck`-class are not created.

I'm not sure why you want to do this, so maybe you can add more information to clearify.

Comment: Thanks I will try that. Basically I want to make use of the GUI components that are created in Deck, from other classes. At the moment I am working around it by making these component variables static and accessing them from the other classes by using Deck.JPanel1, for example. But I think there are better ways of doing it...

Answer (score 1):

No. The super constructor is always called.

But since you extend `JFrame`, what's the point of not creating a window?
You can hide it using `setVisible(false)` in `Pile`'s constructor, but that would be strange.

You should redefine your inheritance hierarchy.

Comment: is it possible to override the superclass's constructor?

Comment: @Kari: No. The super-constructor will be called implicitely before your constructor is called. Please provide more information about why you want to extend a class but not use its behavior.

Answer (score 1):

Ya its happening because the subclass is inheriting the super class constructor.In any subclass always first super class constructor is called.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to do what you want  is to edit the Deck class.

An easy way to do it is just to make a new method in your superclass (init() ) or something, and put all your code in there instead of your constructor. Then overwrite the init() method in your subclass with an empty method (or your own).

Or you could make a new constructor in your superclass with a parameter, like yourConstructor(boolean doNothing). Then you call this constructor in your subclass so it only executes that one and not your default constructor.